# How can I store an object of a class as another class in C++?

Tags: c++, class

Say I have two classes:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    A() {/*...*/}
};

class B {
public:
    B() {/*...*/}
};
```

And store a vector of objects of class `A`:

```cpp
std::vector<A*> objects;
```

How can I **add** an object of class `B` to the vector? My first thought was to use derived classes. It works, but there might be some functions in class `A` that will not be used by any object in class `B`. For example:

```cpp
class A {
public:
    virtual ~A() {};
    A() {/*...*/}
    void doSomething() {/*...*/}
    int returnSomething() {/*...*/}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    B() {/*...*/}
    void doSomethingDifferent() {/*...*/}
    int returnSomethingDifferent() {/*...*/}
};
```

`objects.push_back(objectOfClassB);` works. But when I work with objects of class `B`, I will **never** use the functions (or variables) declared in class `A`.

How could I store an object of a class *as* another class, **without** using derived classes? Or could there be an alternate solution without doing this at all but doing something different with how it's stored?

Comment: You're right to shy away from inheritance when there's nothing, or little, in common between the classes. I think `std::variant` should be helpful, unless you plan on increasing beyond two or three classes stored in the same `vector`.  Why do you want dissimilar data in the same container, anyway? It often winds up a confusing mess, so I recommend thinking hard on whether or not you really want to do this. If you can expand on the real problem you're facing maybe we can offer cleaner alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`std::variant` will do the trick in C++17 or later (see example below), although in some cases you might find it easier just to declare separate `vector<A>` and `vector<B>` objects instead.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
    A() : _x(0) {/*...*/}
    A(int x) : _x(x) {/*...*/}

    int getX() const {return _x;}

private:
    int _x;
};

class B
{
public:
    B() : _y(0.0f) {/*...*/}
    B(float y) : _y(y) {/*...*/}

    float getY() const {return _y;}

private:
    float _y;
};

int main(int, char **)
{
   std::vector< std::variant<A, B> > v;

   v.push_back(A(777));
   v.push_back(B(3.14159f));

   for (auto item : v)
   {
      const A * a = std::get_if<A>(&item);
      if (a)
      {
         std::cout << "The A object has int value x=" << a->getX() << std::endl;
      }
      else
      {
         const B * b = std::get_if<B>(&item);
         if (b)
         {
            std::cout << "The B object has float value y=" << b->getY() << std::endl;
         }
         else
         {
            std::cout << "Hmm, I'm not sure what item is!" << std::endl;
         }
      }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should work for me. But what if I have more than 3 classes that I want to store, or maybe even (hypothetically) 100? Both tricks you mentioned would make a big mess in my code. Again, your solution is fine, and I'm not using this many (3 at most), but what if someone needed to?

Comment: of course it would make a mess. the container needs to know the type and memory imprint of all those classes since your are directly storing the objects in the container instead of pointers. I hardly see a scenario in which this approach is needed, usually you derive the desired classes from a base class/interface and store the pointer/interface pointer. A manager in a video-game in which it has to keep a record of all present entities may seem to be appropriate for your approach; but a better approach would be deriving all entities from an `IEntity` interface and storing the pointers

Comment: In my experience, the objects that you want to store together in the same container will usually have *some* functionality in common; otherwise there would be no reason to store them together.  Given that, moving that common functionality into an interface/superclass and having the various object-types as subclasses is usually the way to go (using `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` or similar to avoid memory-leaks).  If they really have nothing in column, OTOH, then storing them in separate homogenous containers is fine.